# Help needed to add and extra sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino, and already tried to edit this many time. But I cant figure out whats wrong.

The following code has a PIR sensor, 1 LED and 1 buzzer.
I want to add one more PIR sensor, but it should trigger a separate LED , and the same buzzer. In serial monitor.
I have searched many sketches, but all of them seems to have a different method , cant figure out the basics!

```
int ledPin = 13;                // choose the pin for the LED
int inputPin = 2;               // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int pirState = LOW;             // we start, assuming no motion detected
int val = 0;                    // variable for reading the pin status
int pinSpeaker = 10;           //Set up a speaker on a PWM pin (digital 9, 10, or 11)

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input
  pinMode(pinSpeaker, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  val = digitalRead(inputPin);  // read input value
  if (val == HIGH) {            // check if the input is HIGH
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // turn LED ON
    playTone(300, 160);
    delay(150);


    if (pirState == LOW) {
      // we have just turned on
      Serial.println("Motion detected!");
      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = HIGH;
    }
  } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED OFF
      playTone(0, 0);
      delay(300);    
      if (pirState == HIGH){
      // we have just turned off
      Serial.println("Motion ended!");
      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = LOW;
    }
  }
}
// duration in mSecs, frequency in hertz
void playTone(long duration, int freq) {
    duration *= 1000;
    int period = (1.0 / freq) * 1000000;
    long elapsed_time = 0;
    while (elapsed_time < duration) {
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        elapsed_time += (period);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You basically just need to copy and paste the parts of the code that deal with the pir sensor and change the variable names in the copy to something else.  How much of the code that you have now do you actually understand?  If you understand what that code is doing, then repeating it for a second sensor should be trivial.

Comment: @Delta_G, I tried to add duplicate code inside 'loop' for different pins, but it didn't work. I was doing it virtually in https://circuits.io/

Comment: Please post your update (solution) as an answer, then accept it after a while, so we keep the usual question/answer(s) split of the site.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after playing with the code for some time, I just did it!!
pasting the updated code here, may be useful for someone else like me..

```
int ledPin = 13;                // choose the pin for the LED
int ledPinB = 12;               // choose the pin for the LED 2
int inputPin = 2;               // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int inputPinB = 4;              // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor 2)
int pirState = LOW;             // we start, assuming no motion detected
int val1 = 0;                  // variable for reading the pin status
int val2 = 0;                  // variable for reading the pin status
int pinSpeaker = 10;           //Set up a speaker on a PWM pin (digital 9, 10, or 11)

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
  pinMode(ledPinB, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input
  pinMode(inputPinB, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input
  pinMode(pinSpeaker, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  val1 = digitalRead(inputPin);  // read input value
  val2 = digitalRead(inputPinB);  // read input value
  if (val1 == HIGH) {            // check if the input is HIGH
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // turn LED ON
    playTone(300, 160);
    delay(150);


    if (pirState == LOW) {
      // we have just turned on
      Serial.println("Motion detected!");
      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = HIGH;
    }
  } 
  else if (val2 == HIGH) {            // check if the input is HIGH
    digitalWrite(ledPinB, HIGH);  // turn LED ON
    playTone(300, 160);
    delay(150);


    if (pirState == LOW) {
      // we have just turned on
      Serial.println("Motion detected!");
      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = HIGH;
    }
  } 


  else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED OFF
      digitalWrite(ledPinB, LOW); // turn LED OFF
      playTone(0, 0);
      delay(300);    
      if (pirState == HIGH){
      // we have just turned off
      Serial.println("Motion ended!");
      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = LOW;
    }
  }
}
// duration in mSecs, frequency in hertz
void playTone(long duration, int freq) {
    duration *= 1000;
    int period = (1.0 / freq) * 1000000;
    long elapsed_time = 0;
    while (elapsed_time < duration) {
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
        elapsed_time += (period);
    }
}
```

[Link to circuit and virtual demo](https://circuits.io/users/1283839)

Comment: Good job.  Thank you for sharing so we have this in the database.